# Calling main from assembly

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64

I'm writing a small library intended to be used in place of `libc` in a small application. I've read the source of the major `libc` alternatives, but I am unable to get the parameter passing to work for the **x86_64** architecture on Linux.

The library does not require any initialization step in between `_start` and `main`. Since the `libc` and its alternatives do use a initialization step, and my assembly knowledge being limited, I suspect the parameter reordering is causing me troubles.

This is what I've got, which contains assembly inspired from various implementations:

```
.text
.global _start

_start:
    /* Mark the outmost frame by clearing the frame pointer. */
    xorl %ebp, %ebp

    /* Pop the argument count of the stack and place it
     * in the first parameter-passing register. */
    popq %rdi

    /* Place the argument array in the second parameter-passing register. */
    movq %rsi, %rsp

    /* Align the stack at a 16-byte boundary. */
    andq $~15, %rsp

    /* Invoke main (defined by the host program). */
    call main

    /* Request process termination by the kernel. This
     * is x86 assembly but it works for now. */
    mov  %ebx, %eax
    mov  %eax, 1
    int  $80
```

And the entry point is the ordinary main signature: `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. Environment variables etc. are not required for this particular project.

The AMD64 ABI says `rdi` should be used for the first parameter, and `rsi` for the second.

How do I correctly setup the stack and pass the parameters to `main` on Linux x86_64? Thanks!

References:
http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/libc/sysdeps/x86_64/elf/start.S?view=markup
http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/sysdeps/linux/x86_64/crt1.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got

```
 /* Place the argument array in the second parameter-passing register. */
    movq %rsi, %rsp
```

wrong. It should be

```
movq %rsp, %rsi      # move argv to rsi, the second parameter in x86_64 abi
```

Comment: This is AT&T syntax. Comments don't start with a semicolon.

Comment: Fixed. Although I like to mention that on some architectures like HP and PPC comments actually _do_ start with an semicolon

Comment: Doh. I didn't realize GAS took the operands in the opposite order (I wrote this in NASM first, then rewrote in GAS to match the sources more closely). However, the program segfaults now. Thanks for pointing this out though!

Comment: Turns out there were more operands in the opposite order that I overlooked. Everything works like a dream now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`main` is called by [crt0.o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0); see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709998/crt0-o-and-crt1-o-whats-the-difference)

The kernel is setting up the initial stack and process environment after [execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) as specified in the [ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) document (architecture specific); the `crt0` (and related) code is in charge of calling `main`.